# Bold Commerce Product and Subscription Group Connection

Tags: reactjs, subscription, shopify-api-node

I have an e-commerce site using React js connected with Shopify.
I am trying to create a Subscription feature for Products.
I am using the [Bold Subscription App](https://boldcommerce.com/) app. I have installed the app to the Shopify interface. But through the documentations/ API endpoints I am not able to access the subscription groups for each product.
eg In bold subscription app I have created a group "Testing_group" with 3 intervals and added a product "Testing_product". I am able to access all the intervals for testing_group through API endpoint but not the product and as for the product I am able to access all the information about the product through BOLD endpoint or shopify functionality but not the subscription group.
Please do provide any insight, documentation, or code that will help.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Maybe you can provide more info. I am trying to do the same.